# How to add google assistant or alexa to our own websites or apps using their sdk?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I just wanted to know if we can somehow integrate alexa or google assistant onto a website I made. I don't want to make completely new skills or apps. I just wanted to know if I type something, can I get a reply from google assistant or alexa and show on website.

I think Google has some google assistant sdk but then, it's written on python and even the node-js one is dependent on python environments

So is there any chance I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only way to initiate conversation with the smart speaker is by voice. No server side activation, sorry.

Comment: but we have sdk right?

Comment: you can use sdk to perform test calls to your skill and get evaluated result back. Like chatbox.